# Sympy - evalf vs subs

Tags: sympy

I don't get same results using evalf or using subs. Why?

```
from sympy import *

x = Symbol('x')
w = Symbol('w')
b = Symbol('b')
i = Symbol('I')
e = Symbol('E')
c3 = Symbol('c3')

m1 = w*b/2*x
yd1= integrate(-m1/e/i,x)
y1 = integrate(yd1,x)+c3
#yap = y1.evalf(subs={x:0})
yap = y1.subs(x,0)
print(yap)
c3sol = solve(yap,c3)[0]
y1 = y1.subs(c3,c3sol)
print(y1)
```

Using evalf it cannot find the correct solution.

Comment: Show the print - and maybe some intermediate values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`evalf` is used to evaluate to a number; indicating that `x=0` does not reduce the expression to a number, so `subs` is the better choice here.